# New vector with fixed size causes crash

Tags: c++, vector, allocation

### Problem

I had a problem randomly appearing when creating a new vector (pointer) with fixed initial size.

```
std::vector<double> * ret = new std::vector<double>(size);
```

This **sometimes** causes my program to crash an I don't really get why ... maybe stack corruption? I didn't find any explanation on what can cause this issue on the web sadly.

*Example:*

**Code**

```
// <- ... Some independant code
// [size] is an unsigned int passed as parameter to the function
cout << size << endl;
std::vector<double> * ret = new std::vector<double>(size);
cout << "Debug text" << endl;
// More code ... ->
```

**EDIT:** I will update the code as soon as possible to have a clear, minimal, reproductible to have a correct question according to: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://How%20to%20create%20a%20Minimal,%20Complete,%20and%20Verifiable%20example)

**Output**

> 100

... Then it crashes (the trace `"Debug text"` is not printed and the `size` is correct)
I tried putting the critical line of code inside a `try catch` as some people suggested (for memory related errors) but no exception is catched and I still get the crash.
This code is inside a function called multiple times (with various values of `size`, always between `1` and `1000`) and sometimes the function end up witout problem, sometimes not (the value of `size` does not seem to have any infulence but maybe I'm wrong).

**My "solution" (you can skip this part)**

I adapted my code to use a pointer to vector without initial size

```
std::vector<double> * ret;
```

and I uses `push_back()` instead of `[]`.
`[]` was quicker for my algorithm due to how the vector was filled at first (elements order is important and I get positions from external file but I still need a vector and not an array for its dynamic aspect later in code), but I adapted everything to use `push_back()` (less efficient in my case as I now need more iterations but nothing critical).

### Question

In short: Does anyone knows what can be causing the issue OR how I can potentially track what is causing this issue?

Comment: *Does anyone knows what can be causing the issue OR how I can potentially track what is causing this issue*

Track it with `gdb`.

Comment: I'm really curious, why did you `new` the vector? (I ask because 9/10 times, when I see this on SO it was done for a bad reason)

Comment: You really shouldn't be `new`ing standard containers.

Comment: Use valgrind to check for any out-of-bound access, etc.

Comment: Tge crash is a *symptom*. The *cause* is most likely somewhere else, probably earlier and in completely unrelated code. Enable memory checks and/or use a memory checker. Note that the "minimal code" you posted does not reliably reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I will check with gdb and valgrind on my linux as soon as possible (but I an currently working under windows and I am not really used too windows equivalents)

Comment: You don't need tools (other than your brain, that is) to construct a testcase.

Comment: @Borgleader Yes I think it was actually a bad idea to do so (I return that pointer at the end of the function because I need to read (and read only) the content somewhere else). But I did my conception quite rapidly as I needed something functionnal quickly for testing but I think the global structure of the application needs to be reworked.

Comment: @peterchen You may be right as I had a quite similar problem before (when destroying vectors, as I was using pointers, so I get rid of pointers). Yes my minimal code is too minimal ...

Comment: That you don't see "Debug text" is not a reliable indication of the location of the crash.  If you sent that out AND flushed, then you could count on it.

Comment: @smagnan I just tried out [Dr. Memory](https://github.com/DynamoRIO/drmemory/wiki/Downloads), a memory checker akin to valgrind. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Look like your program stopped crashing not because you create a vector without size, but because you use `push_back()`. The fact that replacing `operator[]` with `push_back()` removes your symptom points that somewhere else you access element in a vector out of bounds, corrupt your memory and suddenly get it crashed. Check your code where you access the data.

Comment: As stated before the crash occurs before any access with [] to `ret` elements.

Comment: Is this the first vector you are creating this way?

Comment: @smagnan : you said the allocation was in a loop. Unless crash happens at first iteration you already passed once in the loop accessing one vector, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Slava, no, not the first, so you may be right actually. Could be a corruption on a previous vector maybe? What I found strange is that an out of bound shoud have caused my program to crash before no?

Comment: @smagnan yes that exactly what I meant

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote it seems like you are trying to Access it using `ret[...]` right :-)? Sorry for my smile but this happens when you use a pointer to a vector...

If this is the case you Need to replace it with `(*ret)[...]`

Comment: Actually I am using `(*ret)[...]`. And the crash appears before any access to any `ret` element